# Having trouble determining constants in this assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Consider the following source code, where R, S, and T are constants declared with #define:

```
int A[R][S][T]; 

int store_ele(int i, int j, int k, int *dest)
{ 

*dest = A[i][j][k]; 
 return sizeof(A); 

}
```

In compiling this program, GCC generates the following assembly code:

```
i at %ebp+8, j at %ebp+12, k at %ebp+16, dest at %ebp+20 

1. movl 12(%ebp), %edx    //move j into register %edx 
2. leal (%edx, %edx, 8), %eax //move address %edx+%edx*9 into %eax
3. leal (%edx, %eax, 4), %eax //move address %edx + %eax*4 into %eax
4. imull $111, 8(%ebp), %edx //111*i goes into %edx
5. addl %edx, %eax 
6. addl 16(%ebp), %eax //add k to %eax
7. movl A(, %eax, 4), %edx //%eax*4 offset by address of A moved into %edx 
8. movl 20(%ebp), %eax 
9. movl %edx, (%eax) 
10. movl $888, %eax
```

I know that the last instruction 'movl $888, %eax' says that there are 888 bytes which is equivalent to 222 ints (i * j * k). As you can see I know what each instruction is doing but I am having difficulties reverse engineering this to determine the constants that are being passed into i, j and k.

I am not expecting answers but any hints to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: After looking at the code some more I was able to determine that %edx goes through a bunch of arithmetic, then at instruction 9 %edx is moved as a dereference to %eax (which was set to the address of A at the time). Also, thank you to whoever edited my post to fit an appropriate format, I am a noob at this site.

Comment: nope, I mean gcc's version

Comment: It's on a VM so I will log on and check right now...gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)

Answer (score 7):

The give-away is: `i * 111` = `i * 3 * 37`. Earlier the 2 LEA instructions combine to set `eax = 37 * j`. Adding `k` to sum: `eax = 3 * 37 * i + 37 * j + k`. Since `int` is 4 bytes, and the array size is 888 bytes, the array has 222 elements. The array dimensions are an ordering of the primes: `{2,3,37}`

To expand:

```
edx <- j
eax <- edx + 8 * edx = 9.j
eax <- edx + 4 * eax = j + 4 * 9j = 37.j

edx <- i * 111 = 3 * 37.i
eax <- eax + edx = 3 * 37.i + 37.j
eax <- eax + k = 3 * 37.i + 37.j + k
```

---

Clearly, `(i == 2)` puts us at element `A[222]`, which is out of range. So assuming `(i,j,k)` corresponds to `(R,S,T)`, we have: `R = 2`, where: `(i < 2)`

Similarly, `(j == 36)` yields an index of *at least* `(36 * 37 = 1332)`, so it must correspond to the prime: `S = 3`, where: `(j < 3)` - which leaves: `T = 37`, where: `(k < 37)`.

Therefore we have the array: `A[2][3][37]`, where: `(i < 2, j < 3, k < 37)`

In general the index is: `((((i * S) + j) * T) + k)`, where: `(i < R, j < S, k < T)`

Comment: Brett, thank you so much for your help. I'm hoping I can conceptualize these problems better with more practice. It's very difficult to visualize what a list of asm instructions are doing sometimes

Comment: Can you explain why i * 111 = i * 3 * 37 ?

Comment: @David Because 3*37 = 111

Comment: I got that but where did he get that i*111 was 3*37 in the beginning..?

Comment: @DavidKernin lines 4 & 5, where it offsets the pointer in `%edx`, this combined with the fact that 111 has only two factors (3 and 37): http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+111

Comment: And why should A be A[3][37][2] and not A[2][37][3] ?

Comment: I think there's an error and it should be A[2][37][3]

Comment: @user3296049 - You'll find that translating an algorithm *to* instructions (whatever the architecture) much easier with practice. And a skill that benefits any programmer. Compiling can be thought of as a 'one-way' function of sorts, where semantic (conceptual) information is 'lost'... Trying to *de*-compile assembly can be useful for little fragments of code, but rapidly becomes difficult, or impossible. For example, with the omission of a single line - line 10: `movl $888, %eax` - I couldn't have deduced *anything* about i,j,k.

Comment: I don't understand
"Similarly, (j == 36) yields an index of at least (36 * 37 = 1332), so it must correspond to the prime: S = 3, where: (j < 3) - which leaves: T = 37, where: (k < 37)." How does j == 36?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it, if I'm wrong please correct me since I'm a newbie.

```
1. movl 12(%ebp), %edx    // move j into edx
2. leal (%edx, %edx, 8), %eax // eax = j + j*8 = 9j
3. leal (%edx, %eax, 4), %eax // eax = j + 4*9j = 37j
4. imull $111, 8(%ebp), %edx // edx = 111*i
5. addl %edx, %eax // eax = 111*i + 37j
6. addl 16(%ebp), %eax // eax = 111*i +37j + k
7. movl A(, %eax, 4), %edx // edx = A(eax * 4)
8. movl 20(%ebp), %eax 
9. movl %edx, (%eax) 
10. movl $888, %eax
```

in byte-addressing you would write something like

```
I want the [111][37][3]-th element
```

but since you have a **int** array those indices above must be different (int = 4 byte, I'm assuming that)

111 is only factorizable as 3*37, as the memory layout indicate k is an index in the innermost array, j an index into the middle-array and i an index into the outermost array grouping

```
(2x2x2 case)
( ( ( int, int ), ( int, int ) ), ( ( int, int ), ( int, int ) ) )
```

so in a i=1,j=0,k=0 case, we would have the 111th element taken.

This means the array is `A[2][3][37]` since A[1][0][0] would yield 111*1 + 37*0 + 0 = 111, exactly as 37*3 (all the j and k dimensions at their top capacity) and A[0][2][0] would yield 37*2 (and if you fill the remaining with the k elements you have 111, exactly the i index)

Comment: I got the initial loop index multiplications mixed-up, which I've corrected. You appear to have made a similar error - if you access element: `A[0][36][0]`, the `37.j` term yields: `1332`!

Comment: You're right I put the indices in the wrong order, fixed. Thanks!